# How can I remove Attribute error from my Csv program showing?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, file-handling

I am trying to run a simple CSV program in python(i am just a beginner).On running the program is shows
"AttributeError: partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader' (most likely due to a circular import)"
the code is as follows

```
import csv
f=open("csv.csv",'r')
a=csv.reader(f)
print(a)
```

and the csv file that I have made is as follows:

```
""name,class,section
rakshith,12,science
aditya,12,science
haron,12,science""
```

Plz help!

Comment: Is there a file called `csv.py` in the current working directory? If so you must rename it, and delete any `csv.pyc` file too.

Comment: yeah i did that but it still didnt worked and i even changed the current working directory.I guess it a problem with python 3.8. Let us check another ide and i will post you

Comment: Ok let us know how the other IDE works out.